# Does "complicated-nested" "for/if statement" really follow the C standards?

Tags: c++, c, mingw32

I've known that

```
for (...; ...; ...)
    printf ("Fulfill the limits.");
```

and

```
if  (...)
    printf ("Fulfill the limits.");
```

are C standard.

But

```
for (...; ...; ...)
    if (...)
       for (...; ...; ...)
           if (...)
              for (...; ...; ...)
                  printf ("Fulfill all the limits.");
```

is compiled successfully, and run without (logic) errors.

Does **complicated-nested for/if statement** really follow the C standards or just **mingw32
compiler-specific**?

### Any reference?

Thanks.

Comment: Since when is `if` having semicolons in the parentheses standard?

Comment: @chris sorry, that is a typo. I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly valid syntax. The syntax is not complicated, simply nested like `x1 + (x2 + (x3 + ..)`.

That is, `if/for` *is* a statement and `if/for` *contains* a statement. This can be seen in the [*recursive* BNF grammar rules](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/1999-October/000201.html):

```
statement:
   "if" "(" expression ")" statement |
   "for" "(" expression? ";" expression? ";" expression? ")" statement |
   ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your complicated ( of course not :) ) nested `for`/`if` statement is following the C standard. But

```
 if (...; ...; ...)
```

is not in C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well... While you both are discussing the C grammar, I have read through my reference book. In the book, just as what EricPostpischil said, I cannot find any of the grammar in C Lang. The only thing I could find is that `for(;;) Statement;` and `if() Statement` are correct usage, and the book doesn't mention whether the `complicated-nested` is correct usage or not, but `complicated-nested` can be perfectly compiled with obsolete Turbo C Compiler, and GCC/Mingw.

Comment: @KVD There's no such thing as a "complicated nested" statement. From the grammar, it can be deduced that using an if inside a for inside and if inside a for, etc... is valid. It's implicit, because that (i. e. a recursive definition) is the most convenient way for defining it. So it **is** in the standard, you just have to read it correctly.